# Creating dlls in Visual Studio publishing process

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, publish

To publish a completed C# Asp.NET Web Forms project, I perform the publish process successfully, but 4 .exe files are created under the roslyn folder, they are not accepted by the hosting company. How can I create a dll file instead of an exe file?

`Properties - Application / Output Type = Class Library`

`Properties - Application / Startup Object = (Not set)`

`Properties - Build - Output / Generate Serialization assembly = Off`

`Properties - Build - Output - Advanced / Debugging information = None`

I brought the current settings to this point with the help of ChatGPT, but it constantly creates an exe file.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a test publish to a local folder. This way you can 100% test/check/see if a .exe file is included (it should not be).

However, if after the above simple test?

Then I would suggest you 'remove' the Roslyn compiler extensions.

so, project->manage nuget packages.

You want to delete these 2:

[image]

Now, open the bin folder, then close the project.

Delete everything in that bin folder.

Re open, and do a rebuild solution.

As a suggested step, you would do well to create a new folder called Mycode, and move all of the code modules (if you have any) from App_Code to the folder called MyCode.

The reason for this is that when you built the web site application, everything is compiled and output as ONLY DLLs to the bin folder. However, on demand, some of the file(s) in app_code are STILL going to be compiled by IIS, and you do NOT want that to occur.

You also want to ensure that each of code files you have in MyCode are set as:

[image]

However, it is VERY possible that you don't have, or are not using Roslyn compilers, so you may well not require the above.

As noted, before you do ANY of the above, do a publish to a local folder such as c:\testing\web.

Take a look at the resulting published web site, and check the bin folder.

With the Rosylin compiler extensions removed, then no .exe files should exist.

And, you "may" receive a few compile errors, which in most cases would be if your source code includes some code that "assumes" or "relies" on those compiler extensions.

It is for this VERY important reason I have suggest you MOVE your app_code files OUT of that folder, since on a re-build, you may VERY well miss some compile errors at build time, since code in app_code often can and will STILL be compiled by IIS, and not VS, and that issue you want to avoid.

FYI:
Careful here, since I am suggesting to delete ALL files in bin folder, but ONLY do this if you are 100%, if not 200% sure this is a asp.net web site "applicaiton".

If this is JUST a asp.net web site, then the bin folder cannot be blown out of the water, since that's where .dll references for a asp.net web site are placed.

However, with a asp.net web site? then, yes, you are free to clear out the bin folder (and I highly recommend you do this).